Show that $\mathring{\mathbb Z}=\emptyset$
I want to find interior of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Here is the definition of $\mathring{A}$:
$$\mathring{A}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid \exists r>0:(x-r,x+r)\subseteq A\}$$
My proof:
Suppose on contrary that $\mathring{\mathbb Z}\neq \emptyset$, so $\mathring{\mathbb Z}$ contains at least one element, say $y$. So, there is $r>0$ such that $(y-r,y+r)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. Since $r>0$, we can pick $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r>1/N$; this is possible by Archimedean property. Then we have $y+\frac{1}{N}\in (y-r,y+r)$, but $\mathbb{Z}$ does not contain rational numbers, a contradiction.
Concerns:
What I am unsure about is if I used  Archimedean property correctly, because it says "for all" $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\varepsilon>1/N$. Here, in my proof, the value $r>0$ is not arbitrarily given, only that it exists.

I would not accept this as a correct proof because contrary to your statement $\mathbb Z$ does contain rational numbers.
One way to fix it is to require $N>1$ and then note that $y+\frac1N$ is not an integer, which is different from saying that it is a rational number.
Edit after the concern was made explicit:
Your logical combination between the existence of an $x>0$ (such that $(y-x,y+x)\subseteq\mathbb Z$) and the Archimedean property is correct, but the rest of the proof isn't (see above).

The reason why I believed $y+1/N$ was rational is because $y$ is integer, and $y+1/N=(yN+1)/N$

But it is rational. Only your claim that $\mathbb Z$ does not contain rational numbers is false. So merely observing that $y+1/N$ is rational, while true, does not generate the contradiction you want.

I think I wasn't clear what I meant: Since $y+1/N$ is rational and belongs to $B(y,r)$, and since $B(y,r)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, it would mean that $y+1/N\in \mathbb{Z}$, which is a contradiction. But I agree that it was wrong to say that $\mathbb{Z}$ did not contain rational numbers. What was enough to say is that $y+1/N$ isn't an integer, as you said.

Plus the requirement that $N>1,$ otherwise $y+1/N$ could still be an integer. Alternatively, you can use $y+1/(N+2)$ which is non-integer from the start.
